# Jest snapshot testing error: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I want to write snapshot test for my `Footer` component, but it throws error: `You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>`. Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'

import Footer from '../footer'

it('Footer renders correctly', () => {
    const tree = renderer
        .create(<Footer />)
        .toJSON()

    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

I know this happens because `Footer` component uses `Link` from `react-router-dom`. In order to solve this problem I wrapped `Footer` component in `BrowserRouter`:

```
const tree = renderer
    .create(
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Footer />
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
    .toJSON()
```

but now it throws error: `Browser history needs a DOM`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used `MemoryRouter` instead of `BrowserRouter` and it solved the problem.

```
import React from 'react'
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'

import Footer from '../footer'

it('Footer renders correctly', () => {
const tree = renderer
    .create(
        <MemoryRouter>
            <Footer />
        </MemoryRouter>
    )
    .toJSON()

    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

Comment: If anyone is still having issues due to keys not matching in the snapshot. You can follow [this](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/5579) example and add `initialEntries={[ { pathname: '/', key: 'testKey' } ]}` or `keyLength={0}` in the MemoryRouter