# Snapshot testing error: Element type is invalid: expected a string [...]

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to do some simple snapshot testing using React and Jest.

Initially I was getting this error: `Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>`

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55791828/jest-snapshot-testing-error-you-should-not-use-link-outside-a-router) I updated my test and wrapped the component I'm testing in: `<MemoryRouter>...</MemoryRouter>`. Once I did this, I started getting a new error: `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.` I have no idea what that means.

My test:

```
import React from "react";
import BookTile from "./BookTile";
import MemoryRouter from "react-router-dom";
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";

test("my test", () => {
    let book = {};
    const component = renderer.create(
        <MemoryRouter>
            <BookTile book={book} />
        </MemoryRouter>
    )
    let tree = component.toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
})
```

The component I'm testing:

```
import React from "react";

import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

export default function BookTile(props) {
    return (
        <Link to={`/book/${props.book.id}`}>
            <div className="book-tile" style={{'backgroundImage': `url(${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/uploads/${props.book.cover_image_file_name})`}}>
                <div className='book-tile-title'>
                    {props.book.title}
                </div>
            </div>
        </Link>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not importing memory router correctly. Here's how it should look like:

```
import {MemoryRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
```

Comment: i am importing it like you suggest and getting the error...